# Symfony Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: symfony

I use Symfony components in own framework. I installed DI component and tried to get it in my BaseController but all the time I get the same error:

> Call to a member function get() on null

My base controller:

```
abstract class BaseController implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;
    ...
}
```

And when I try to access `$this->container->get('ser_id');` return call to a member function.

How to slove this?

Update:

only work if i include in my controller service container

```
$this->service_container = include __DIR__ .'/../../../container.php';
```

and use it like this:

```
$this->service_container->get('id');
```

Comment: Whatever code is creating the controller needs to call setContainer on it.  The Symfony framework controller resolver does this for you.  You will need to adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: you need to extend ContainerAware class instead of implements ContainerAwareInterface.

Comment: Jasmin Mistry `ContainerAware` class does not exist.

Comment: And the trait takes care of the implementation.  Just need to call setContainer when you create the controller.

Comment: Ok that is not a problem. But what `setContainer` need to return. What to pass inside ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a little bit old question, but maybe someone will stuck with this problem. After implementing `ContainerAwareInterface` and `use ContainerAwareTrait` you will need to call setContainer. Example:

```
// Controller or Service class
class SomeClass implements ContainerAwareInterface {
   use ContainerAwareTrait;

   //some logic
   //..........
}

// services.yml 
your_controller:
    class: SomeClass
    calls:
        - [ setContainer, [ '@service_container' ] ]
```